# MySQL PHP incompatibility

Tags: php, mysql

I'm running WAMP locally, but connecting to a remote MySQL database.  The local version of PHP is the latest 5.3.0.

One of the remote databases, being version 5.0.45 works fine.  However, the other remote database I'm trying to connect to, which is version 5.0.22 throws the following error before dying:

> Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: OK packet 6 bytes shorter than expected. PID=5880 in ...
>
> Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: mysqlnd cannot connect to MySQL 4.1+ using old authentication in ...

WTF?

**UPDATE:**

Reverting to PHP 5.2.* i.e. anything lower than 5.3.0 resolves the problem completely.  As long as I am not running 5.3.0 I can connect to both databases. I'm not sure what the explanation is for this weirdness.

Comment: mysqlnd isn't part of 5.2, i.e. you're using another connector/lib now that you've reverted to php 5.2.

Comment: so what would the issue with 5.3 have likely been then?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The MySQL account you're using probably has an old 16 character long password (hash).
You can test that with a MySQL client (like HeidiSQL, the MySQL console client or any other client) and an account that has access to the `mysql`.`user` table. If the Password field contains 16 chars it's an old password and [mysqlnd](http://php.net/mysqli.mysqlnd) cannot use it to connect to the MySQL server.
You can set a new password for that user with

```
SET PASSWORD FOR 'username'@'hostmask' = PASSWORD('thepassword')
```

see [dev_mysql_set_password](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/set-password.html)

edit:
You should also check if the server is set to [use/create old passwords by default](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_old-passwords).

edit2:
Please run the query

```
SELECT
  Length(`Password`),
  Substring(`Password`, 1, 1)
FROM
  `mysql`.`user`
WHERE
  `user`='username'
```

on the 5.0.22 server (the one that's "failing"). Replace `username` by the account you're using in mysql_connect().
What does that return?

Comment: no both authentications are the same and not as lengthy as that.

Comment: "not as lengthy"? I do not mean the plain password but the hash stored in the user table ;-) The old algorithm used 16 characters, the new ...uhm... 40?

Comment: yeah... still not working sorry.  This is a weird error it's annoying me.

Comment: Ok, let's test whether you still have old passwords. see edit2.

Comment: getting guys at work to check if this is the case, updates in a sec.  But for now the older PHP version seems to work for whatever reason.

Comment: I would have never guessed this answer.  You rock!  I owe you dinner some day.

Comment: is there no way to tell the client to use the old passwords? I can't change what is happening on the host. I'm trying to develop towards an existing app. I have no idea how to modify xampp to use an older version of php.

Answer (score 7):

I have been trying to find a simple fix for this problem. Try this approach. In MySQL type

```
SELECT Host, User, Password FROM mysql.user;
```

If your password is sixteen characters, this is because you have used OLD_PASSWORD on your user's or have been running an old version of MySQL. To update type in

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('newpass')
  WHERE User='root' AND Host='localhost';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

swapping root, localhost and newpass for your user, host and pass respectively. Now when you re-type

```
SELECT Host, User, Password FROM mysql.user;
```

Your password should have changed. This fixed it for me.

Comment: Simplest fix! Updating the password to the same old password (Password=PASSWORD('oldpass')) works as well though.

Comment: If the server still creates 16-character passwords by default, you can fix this still: create the 41-character hash on your local machine with `SELECT PASSWORD('yourpass');`, then copy the printed hash into a command like this and execute it on the server machine: `UPDATE mysql.user SET Password='yourhash' WHERE User='root'; FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`.

Answer (score 4):

Your database server is set to use old passwords by default. The error message you get is mysqlnd seeing a database that can support the new (safer) authentication but refuses to do so. In such a case, mysqlnd aborts the connection and refuses to work.

Make sure your my.cnf does not have

```
old-passwords = 1
```

After you comment out that setting from my.cnf (or remove it from where else it might be set), and restart your server, make sure to re-set your password using the command VolkerK describes, otherwise you won't be able to log in.

Comment: I do not have ol-passwords = 1 in my my.ini so how do I change the database server to not use old passwords

Comment: @sid: MySQL can load multiple configuration files, and you need to make sure none of them have old passwords enabled. Another possibility is that you have the global variable `old_passwords` set to 1. To check, run `SELECT @@global.old_passwords;`

Answer (score 3):

A more simple solution is to delete the database user and create a new one with the same username and password.

Comment: This happened to me when i decided to update my `ppa:ondrej/php`. I also had to update my apache2 service. Long story short, this mysql issue happened to me.

I just wanted to say that this solution worked for me, and I didn't even need to go through the hassle of creating a new user. I simply had to just update the password of my existing user. I hope this helps someone else down the road. 

Thank you for your brief and working solution.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using MySQL 8 or above, the [default authentication plugin](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_default_authentication_plugin) is [`caching_sha2_password`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/caching-sha2-pluggable-authentication.html), so to downgrade to `mysql_native_password` (in case of PHP incompatibility), set it in `my.cfg`, e.g.

```
[mysqld]
default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
```

then restart MySQL service.

See: [Upgrading to MySQL 8.0 : Default Authentication Plugin Considerations](https://mysqlserverteam.com/upgrading-to-mysql-8-0-default-authentication-plugin-considerations/) & [Native Pluggable Authentication](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/native-pluggable-authentication.html).

If still won't work, change the root password as suggested in the accepted answer, e.g.

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password by 'root';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Related:

- [MySQL remote connection fails with “unknown authentication method”](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14612551/55075)
- [mysql_connect(): The server requested authentication method unknown to the client](https://serverfault.com/q/385378/130437)
- [Multiple MySQL Versions for Development](https://gist.github.com/benlinton/d24471729ed6c2ace731)
- [Mysql. The server requested authentication method unknown to the client](https://github.com/laradock/laradock/issues/1390)

Answer (score 2):

As the user Evernoob above said:

**"Reverting to PHP 5.2.* i.e. anything lower than 5.3.0 resolves the problem completely. As long as I am not running 5.3.0 I can connect to both databases. I'm not sure what the explanation is for this weirdness"**

In the case of connecting to a shared hose (in our case DreamHost), who is using the oldpassword option, we could not modify the users table.  These suggested options will work in other scenarios, just not with shared web hosting.

Of note, we are running WAMP.

Answer (score 1):

My webhost has different versions of PHP/MySQL configured and to use a certain one I need to use the correct .php extension - notably .php5  It might be something as simple as that.

Answer (score 1):

Reverting to PHP 5.2.* did the trick!  THANK YOU!

If you're using WAMP... left click wamp > php > version> get more>

select the version you want and download.

install/run the exe

left click wamp > php > version> PHP 5.2.*

That fixed this issue. I couldn't run any of these SQL commands without getting a "command denied to user 'XXX'@'localhost'" error.  Good look trying to log on as SU 'Root'. Maybe on a personal server, but not going to happen on a real host.

Answer (score 1):

I just had this problem with a Wordpress site that suddenly stopped working and displayed this error.

I found a GUI in the website's Control Panel that allowed me to change the password for the database user. I tried changing it to the current password and this was not allowed because the current password was not strong enough.

I changed the database password to a new, stronger password and edited my wp-config.php file to have the new password.

This worked!

So my guess is, the hosting provider upgraded something, maybe MySQL, to a version that requires stronger passwords. The fix for me was to use the cpanel GUI to change the database user's password, and update wp-config.php to match.

Answer (score 1):

After lots of search and tries I found a way without needage to any downgrade/upgrade of MySQL and any affect on other users of running instance of MySQL.

The solution is to resetting password by:

for MySQL versions newer than 5.7.5 ( > 5.7.5):

> ALTER USER 'mysqlUsername'@'hostname' IDENTIFIED WITH
>   mysql_native_password BY 'mysqlUsernamePassword';

for older versions of MySQL: ( <= 5.7.5)

> SET PASSWORD FOR 'mysqlUsername'@'hostname' =
>   PASSWORD('mysqlUsernamePassword');

I found the point [here](https://serverfault.com/a/938785/375177)!

It made mine working well!