# Remote Mysql Server connection by PHP

Tags: php

While i execute following code:

```
$db_host = "<IP>";  // Host name
$db_user = "<usr>";  // User name of your database
$db_password = "<pass>";     // Password of your database
$db_name="<db name>";   // Database name

$con = mysql_connect($db_host,$db_user,$db_password);
mysql_select_db($db_name) or die("Cannot select database...");
```

It shows following errors:

**Warning**: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: OK packet 6 bytes shorter than expected in C:\wamp\www\limosbusesjets\connection.php on line 21

**Warning**: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: mysqlnd cannot connect to MySQL 4.1+ using old authentication in C:\wamp\www\limosbusesjets\connection.php on line 21
    Cannot select database...

Comment: The errors shown are missing. Could you please add them?

Answer (score 3):

These errors generally happen when one is using **PHP 5.3**, and its new **mysqlnd driver** to connect to MySQL *(which is often the case with PHP 5.3, as it's one of the new stuff introduced with 5.3 -- and "mysqlnd" is mentionned in your second error)* : with those, **you cannot connect to a MySQL database using the old-passwords system**.

Which means you'll have to change the way your MySQL server deals with passwords, to switch to the "new" authentication system.

See, for instance :

- [Resolving the "OK packet 6 bytes shorter than expected"](http://www.ars-informatica.ca/article.php?article=82)
- [MySQL PHP incompatibility.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1340488/mysql-php-incompatibility)
- [Backward Incompatible Changes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/migration53.incompatible.php)

Not sure it's what is causing the problem in your case, but that's one common MySQL related thing, with PHP 5.3, for those errors...