# Debugging Zend project

Tags: debugging, zend-framework, zend-db, php-5.4

I have transferred a working zend project to another server. It is a main domain and everything is set up correctly (I think). Header and footer are working good but in the middle content area it displays error messages.

```
Server IP: 67.225.249.200
User agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.116 Safari/537.36
Server time: 2013-07-10 02:50:43
RequestURI: /
Message: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2054] The server requested authentication method umknown to the client

Trace:
#0 /home/xienc2/public_html/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(109): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->_connect()
#1 /home/xienc2/public_html/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(459): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->_connect()
#2 /home/xienc2/public_html/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('DESCRIBE `page`', Array)
#3 /home/xienc2/public_html/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(169): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('DESCRIBE `page`')
#4 /home/xienc2/public_html/library/Zend/Db/Table/Abstract.php(835): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->describeTable('page', NULL)
#5 /home/xienc2/public_html/library/Zend/Db/Table/Abstract.php(874): Zend_Db_Table_Abstract->_setupMetadata()
#6 /home/xienc2/public_html/library/Zend/Db/Table/Abstract.php(982): Zend_Db_Table_Abstract->_setupPrimaryKey()
#7 /home/xienc2/public_html/library/Zend/Db/Table/Select.php(100): Zend_Db_Table_Abstract->info()
#8 /home/xienc2/public_html/library/Zend/Db/Table/Select.php(78): Zend_Db_Table_Select->setTable(Object(Application_Model_DbTable_Page))
#9 /home/xienc2/public_html/library/Zend/Db/Table/Abstract.php(1018): Zend_Db_Table_Select->__construct(Object(Application_Model_DbTable_Page))
#10 /home/xienc2/public_html/library/Zend/Db/Table/Abstract.php(1326): Zend_Db_Table_Abstract->select()
#11 /home/xienc2/public_html/application/models/PageMapper.php(57): Zend_Db_Table_Abstract->fetchAll()
#12 /home/xienc2/public_html/application/controllers/IndexController.php(7): Application_Model_PageMapper->fetchAll()
#13 /home/xienc2/public_html/library/Zend/Controller/Action.php(133): IndexController->init()
#14 /home/xienc2/public_html/library/Zend/Controller/Dispatcher/Standard.php(268): Zend_Controller_Action->__construct(Object(Zend_Controller_Request_Http), Object(Zend_Controller_Response_Http), Array)
#15 /home/xienc2/public_html/library/Zend/Controller/Front.php(954): Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Standard->dispatch(Object(Zend_Controller_Request_Http), Object(Zend_Controller_Response_Http))
#16 /home/xienc2/public_html/library/Zend/Application/Bootstrap/Bootstrap.php(97): Zend_Controller_Front->dispatch()
#17 /home/xienc2/public_html/library/Zend/Application.php(366): Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap->run()
#18 /home/xienc2/public_html/public/index.php(30): Zend_Application->run()
#19 {main}

Request data: array (
'controller' => 'index',
'action' => 'index',
'module' => 'default',
)

Session data:


Last database query: connect

Last database query params: array (
)
```

My host is Liquidweb.

Php version is 5.4.16 and pdo extention is also installed. Please help.

Comment: I temporary solved this problem by using mysqli instead of pdo_mysql. The server has pdo_mysql but not sure why it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

You could be experiencing one of the [**Backward incompatibility issues**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/migration53.incompatible.php) with PHP versions >= 5.3.

The most probable cause is the :

> The new mysqlnd library necessitates the use of MySQL 4.1's newer 41-byte password format. Continued use of the old 16-byte passwords will cause mysql_connect() and similar functions to emit the error, "mysqlnd cannot connect to MySQL 4.1+ using old authentication."

Check your MySQL server version. Then check your MySQL password store. [This answer provides more insight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14612551/mysql-remote-connection-fails-with-unknown-authentication-method).

Comment: I can connect the db using mysql_connect directly and even able to fetch records. But through zend pdo it throws errors. Is it still a php version problem?

Comment: Well a web Server could be configured to run several PHP versions at once so check what the PHP version that Zend is running under is. 
What is the Zend version?

Comment: Zend Version: 1.11.11 Release (r24485) and PHP Version: 5.4.16

Comment: I changed the resources.db.adapter from pdo_mysql to mysqli and it is working good. Is it a pdo version problem?

Comment: Don't think so. Maybe the mysql extension is outdated. Mysqli is newer. It seems that I was partially right - it was a version of an extension.