# mysqli on hosted servers

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am on a hosted server. I use mysql commands to access the database. However, when I try to use mysqli commands, which are suppose to be more secure, I get the following response: 
The server requested authentication method unknown to the client. 
I went to a different host and now I get: 
Fatal error: Call to undefined function: mysqli_connect(). 
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: First, you should create a php test file (test.php) containing `<?php phpinfo() ?>`. Open this page in your browser and make sure you have the mysql/mysqli extension loaded in your php. The mysqli_connect function requires, on ubuntu for example, the php5-mysql package to be installed, according the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.installation.php).

Comment: I did as you said, and mysqli seems to be running. However, every time I try to use it I still get the following error: The server requested authentication method unknown to the client. Mysql works perfectly, but mysqli has this authentication error.

Comment: maybe this link will help you : 1. [DBA Stackexchange](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/34024/server-requested-authentication-method-unknown-to-the-client-mysql-old-password) 2. [MySQL Remote Connection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14612551/mysql-remote-connection-fails-with-unknown-authentication-method)

Answer (score 0):

You should upgrade your PHP it's enabled by default in the last versions.

If you cannot do this then you need to go into the `php.ini` file and uncomment that extension.

Comment: Again, this is on a hosted server. This is not my personal server, so I cannot adjust the php.ini file.

Comment: I have u 2 options upgrade php u can do it on a shared server

Comment: The php version on the shared server is PHP 5.5.22. There is no option to upgrade any further. I have no access to the php.ini file. The same error keeps popping up.

Comment: I suggest you get in contact with your hosting service or you can try PDO, its better anyway

Answer (score 0):

make sure you have the mysql/mysqli extension loaded in your php

```
php -m | grep -i mysql
```

You will get result :

```
[root@yourserver ~]# php -m | grep -i mysql
mysql
mysqli
pdo_mysql
```

Comment: This is not my server. This is on a hosted server, so I have no access to adjust the php files.