# Mysql Connecting error. PDO throwing SQLSTATE [HY000] [2054]

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to connect the mysql with PDO but having a problem.PDOException is throwing this problem :

`PDO::__construct(): The server requested authentication method unknown to the client [mysql_old_password]`

`SQLSTATE[HY000] [2054] The server requested authentication method unknown to the client`

I have tried `SET old_passwords = 0;` But still not working.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL remote connection fails with "unknown authentication method"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14612551/mysql-remote-connection-fails-with-unknown-authentication-method)

Answer (score 0):

You're close, but in the absence of any modifier, [you were only setting a session variable](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/set-statement.html).

To set a global variable, try this:

```
SET GLOBAL old_passwords=0
```

Or, better yet, edit your config file with `old-passwords=0` and restart.

If you have old accounts with the old password format set, [you'll need to upgrade them as well](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/account-upgrades.html).

Comment: How can i restart?I am using remote server.Not local one

Comment: Well that's a whole separate question. If this isn't your database you should be talking to your database administrator about that.

Comment: thi error comes `#1227 - Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER privilege(s) for this operation` when i use `SET GLOBAL old_passwords=0`