# mysqli_real_connect(): The server requested authentication method unknown to the client [sha256_password]

Tags: php, mysqli

> mysqli_real_connect(): The server requested authentication method
>   unknown to the client [sha256_password]

I recently changed my MySQL root access details (password) and enabled encryption.

Settings were accepted but after signing-out, I couldn't sign-in again. 
I am running PHP-5.6.25 and Mysql-5.7.14 on Wamp64 - server.

Is it possible to reverse settings to defaults and or make changes?

Any help is  highly appreciated.

Comment: Also, this isn't really about code I believe. Related? https://serverfault.com/questions/385378/mysql-connect-the-server-requested-authentication-method-unknown-to-the-clien and related? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14612551/mysql-remote-connection-fails-with-unknown-authentication-method

Answer (score -3):

The cause for this issue may be the port used by other database.
Check the service like mysql80 is running on your port and stop the service it is the mysql application and it can be of another database that can use this port.Now run you wampserver, the phpmyadmin will have mysqld services that runs on background.

Comment: Seems unrelated.