# phpmyadmin #2054 cannot log in to the mysql server

Tags: php, mysql, apache, phpmyadmin

I am a newbie in MySQL, Apache, PHP, and phpMyAdmin. The first server I built was on Windows Vista x32bit and it was successful. Then, I try to build the second server on another laptop, it is Windows 7 x64bit and it stucked in error code #2054. I use 'localhost' with a fixed IP address. I installed the server individually from .msi files, NOT a package installer.

After I enter my 'root' and my 'password', then I clicked 'Go', it popped up two error messages, one is "#2054 Cannot log in to the MySQL server" and another is "Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed."

I searched many resources online, but out of luck.

How can I solve these two errors?

Any info in helpful. Thanks in advance.

Below is my config.inc.php:

```
enter code here <?php
/* vim: set expandtab sw=4 ts=4 sts=4: */
/**
 * phpMyAdmin sample configuration, you can use it as base for
 * manual configuration. For easier setup you can use setup/
 *
 * All directives are explained in Documentation.html and on phpMyAdmin
 * wiki <http://wiki.phpmyadmin.net>.
 *
 * @package PhpMyAdmin
 */

 /*
  * This is needed for cookie based authentication to encrypt password in
  * cookie
  */
 $cfg['blowfish_secret'] = 'a8b7c6d'; /* YOU MUST FILL IN THIS FOR COOKIE AUTH! */

 /*
  * Servers configuration
  */
 $i = 0;

 /*
  * First server
  */
 $i++;
/* Authentication type */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
/* Server parameters */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress'] = false;
/* Select mysql if your server does not have mysqli */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = false;

/*
 * phpMyAdmin configuration storage settings.
 */

/* User used to manipulate with storage */
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlhost'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controluser'] = 'phpmyadmin';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlpass'] = 'johan1234';

/* Storage database and tables */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pmadb'] = 'phpmyadmin';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['bookmarktable'] = 'pma_bookmark';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['relation'] = 'pma_relation';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_info'] = 'pma_table_info';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_coords'] = 'pma_table_coords';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pdf_pages'] = 'pma_pdf_pages';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['column_info'] = 'pma_column_info';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['history'] = 'pma_history';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_uiprefs'] = 'pma_table_uiprefs';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['tracking'] = 'pma_tracking';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['designer_coords'] = 'pma_designer_coords';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['userconfig'] = 'pma_userconfig';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['recent'] = 'pma_recent';
/* Contrib / Swekey authentication */
// $cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_swekey_config'] = '/etc/swekey-pma.conf';

/*
 * End of servers configuration
 */

/*
 * Directories for saving/loading files from server
 */
$cfg['UploadDir'] = '';
$cfg['SaveDir'] = '';

/**
 * Defines whether a user should be displayed a "show all (records)"
 * button in browse mode or not.
 * default = false
 */
//$cfg['ShowAll'] = true;

/**
 * Number of rows displayed when browsing a result set. If the result
 * set contains more rows, "Previous" and "Next".
 * default = 30
 */
//$cfg['MaxRows'] = 50;

/**
 * Use graphically less intense menu tabs
 * default = false
 */
//$cfg['LightTabs'] = true;

/**
 * disallow editing of binary fields
 * valid values are:
 *   false  allow editing
 *   'blob' allow editing except for BLOB fields
 *   'all'  disallow editing
 * default = blob
 */
//$cfg['ProtectBinary'] = 'false';

/**
 * Default language to use, if not browser-defined or user-defined
 * (you find all languages in the locale folder)
 * uncomment the desired line:
 * default = 'en'
 */
//$cfg['DefaultLang'] = 'en';
//$cfg['DefaultLang'] = 'de';

/**
 * default display direction (horizontal|vertical|horizontalflipped)
 */
//$cfg['DefaultDisplay'] = 'vertical';


/**
 * How many columns should be used for table display of a database?
 * (a value larger than 1 results in some information being hidden)
 * default = 1
 */
//$cfg['PropertiesNumColumns'] = 2;

/**
 * Set to true if you want DB-based query history.If false, this utilizes
 * JS-routines to display query history (lost by window close)
 *
 * This requires configuration storage enabled, see above.
 * default = false
 */
//$cfg['QueryHistoryDB'] = true;

/**
 * When using DB-based query history, how many entries should be kept?
 *
 * default = 25
 */
//$cfg['QueryHistoryMax'] = 100;

/*
 * You can find more configuration options in Documentation.html
 * or here: http://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/pma/Config
 */
?>
```

Comment: can you post config.inc.php content (the files is located in \xampp\phpmyadmin) ?

Comment: Yea @IswantoSan is right, post the config so we can help you better.

Comment: sorry about that. The config.inc.php is posted now.

Comment: @Iswanto San I tried it, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try to set host property in phpmyadmin/config.inc.php :

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1';
```

Answer (score 1):

I found it. I found the answer of my own question. Here is the link:

[MySQL PHP incompatibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1340488/mysql-php-incompatibility)

It answered by Matt, he wrote:

> I have been trying to find a simple fix for this problem. Try this approach. In MySQL type

```
SELECT Host, User, Password FROM mysql.user;
```

> If your password is sixteen characters, this is because you have used OLD_PASSWORD on your user's or have been running an old version of MySQL. To update type in

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('newpass')
  WHERE User='root' AND Host='localhost';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

> swapping root, localhost and newpass for your user, host and pass respectively. Now when you re-type

```
SELECT Host, User, Password FROM mysql.user;
```

> Your password should have changed. This fixed it for me.