# Need help sorting out MySQL permissions and connections

Tags: php, mysql, database

So I'm trying to set up a PHP site that accesses and writes to a database.  This should be relatively simple but I've become swamped with a mess of permission issues and I'm new to PHP so I'm not sure how to fix them all.

First off, this warning occurs when trying to access the database:

```
Warning: mysqli_connect(): The server requested authentication method unknown to the client [mysql_old_password]
```

The connection also fails due to this:

```
Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2054): The server requested authentication method umknown to the client
```

In my research I found that this warning was related to password hashing due to versioning of PHP ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1340488/mysql-php-incompatibility/1340538#1340538))

However attempting to run the solution on that page gives me the following error:

```
Error Code: 1044. Access denied for user 'user'@'host' to database 'mysql'
```

And I don't know how to gain permissions in that database.

Here's my php code for reference (sensitive info removed):

```
$con=mysqli_connect("IP:port","user","password","database_name");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
else
{
    echo "Succesfully connected";
echo "<br />";
}

$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM OWNERS") or die("Error: ".mysqli_error($con));
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
  echo $row['email'] . " " . $row['type'];
echo "<br />";
}
```

Can someone help me out with this one?  I know it's a lot but it seems like all of the issues are related and I'm not sure where to start with fixing them.  (I'm using XAMPP to run the php and MySQL workbench to run queries)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the mysql is running on a different machine in your network. try this to see if it works:

```
CREATE USER 'user'@'IP' IDENTIFIED BY 'your password';
GRANT ALL ON database_name.* TO 'user'@'IP';
```

if the user is already in your system but with different IP then you should create it again using the IP of your mysql server. you could also try **%** instead of IP in create user and grant statements but it is not recommended in production.

Comment: I'm using a hostgator database, I created the user through their services, but when I run the user through workbench its on my IP.  Is that a problem?  I've checked the privileges for the account using SHOW GRANTS and it has full privileges.

Comment: but can you connect to mysql from the hostgator webserver? might be a firewall problem. it's not a good idea to open mysql port to the internet and let anyone try and connect to it.

Comment: the hostgator only lets you create databases and users, not modify them.  You can grant permissions when creating users and all the permissions have been checked.  You have to use an outside application like mySQL workbench to actually modify the databases.