# How to resolve php functional errors?

Tags: php, html, mysql, apache, error-handling

I recently installed PHP with Apache and MySQL manually. I decided to develop a login page with PHP for my website with Apache as web server and MySQL as database for validation of login credentials. It has 5 parts:

1. **config.php** for connection with database
2. **register.php** where new users can register themselves
3. **login.php** where existing users can log on
4. **welcome.php** where users are redirected after successful login and
5. **logout.php** for logout.

I have used object-oriented PHP script for developing these pages. here are my codes:

**config.php**

```
<?php
/* Database credentials. I am running MySQL
server with default setting (user 'root' with 'root' password) */
define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost');
define('DB_USERNAME', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'root');
define('DB_NAME', 'LoginData');

/* Attempt to connect to MySQL database */
$mysqli = new mysqli(DB_SERVER, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

// Check connection
if($mysqli === false){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . $mysqli->connect_error);
}
?>
```

**register.php**

```
<?php
// Include config file
require_once 'config.php';

// Define variables and initialize with empty values
$username = $password = $confirm_password = "";
$username_err = $password_err = $confirm_password_err = "";

// Processing form data when form is submitted
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){

    // Validate username
    if(empty(trim($_POST["username"]))){
        $username_err = "Please enter a username.";
    } else{
        // Prepare a select statement
        $sql = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = ?";

        if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql)){
            // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
            $stmt->bind_param("s", $param_username);

            // Set parameters
            $param_username = trim($_POST["username"]);

            // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
            if($stmt->execute()){
                // store result
                $stmt->store_result();

                if($stmt->num_rows == 1){
                    $username_err = "This username is already taken.";
                } else{
                    $username = trim($_POST["username"]);
                }
            } else{
                echo "Oops! Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
            }
        }

        // Close statement
        $stmt->close();
    }

    // Validate password
    if(empty(trim($_POST['password']))){
        $password_err = "Please enter a password.";     
    } elseif(strlen(trim($_POST['password'])) < 6){
        $password_err = "Password must have atleast 6 characters.";
    } else{
        $password = trim($_POST['password']);
    }

    // Validate confirm password
    if(empty(trim($_POST["confirm_password"]))){
        $confirm_password_err = 'Please confirm password.';     
    } else{
        $confirm_password = trim($_POST['confirm_password']);
        if($password != $confirm_password){
            $confirm_password_err = 'Password did not match.';
        }
    }

    // Check input errors before inserting in database
    if(empty($username_err) && empty($password_err) && empty($confirm_password_err)){

        // Prepare an insert statement
        $sql = "INSERT INTO users (username, password) VALUES (?, ?)";

        if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql)){
            // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
            $stmt->bind_param("ss", $param_username, $param_password);

            // Set parameters
            $param_username = $username;
            $param_password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT); // Creates a password hash

            // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
            if($stmt->execute()){
                // Redirect to login page
                header("location: login.php");
            } else{
                echo "Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
            }
        }

        // Close statement
        $stmt->close();
    }

    // Close connection
    $mysqli->close();
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Sign Up</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css">
    <style type="text/css">
        body{ font: 14px sans-serif; }
        .wrapper{ width: 350px; padding: 20px; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <h2>Sign Up</h2>
        <p>Please fill this form to create an account.</p>
        <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="post">
            <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($username_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
                <label>Username</label>
                <input type="text" name="username"class="form-control" value="<?php echo $username; ?>">
                <span class="help-block"><?php echo $username_err; ?></span>
            </div>    
            <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($password_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
                <label>Password</label>
                <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $password; ?>">
                <span class="help-block"><?php echo $password_err; ?></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($confirm_password_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
                <label>Confirm Password</label>
                <input type="password" name="confirm_password" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $confirm_password; ?>">
                <span class="help-block"><?php echo $confirm_password_err; ?></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit">
                <input type="reset" class="btn btn-default" value="Reset">
            </div>
            <p>Already have an account? <a href="login.php">Login here</a>.</p>
        </form>
    </div>    
</body>
</html>
```

**login.php**

```
<?php
// Include config file
require_once 'config.php';

// Define variables and initialize with empty values
$username = $password = "";
$username_err = $password_err = "";

// Processing form data when form is submitted
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){

    // Check if username is empty
    if(empty(trim($_POST["username"]))){
        $username_err = 'Please enter username.';
    } else{
        $username = trim($_POST["username"]);
    }

    // Check if password is empty
    if(empty(trim($_POST['password']))){
        $password_err = 'Please enter your password.';
    } else{
        $password = trim($_POST['password']);
    }

    // Validate credentials
    if(empty($username_err) && empty($password_err)){
        // Prepare a select statement
        $sql = "SELECT username, password FROM users WHERE username = ?";

        if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql)){
            // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
            $stmt->bind_param("s", $param_username);

            // Set parameters
            $param_username = $username;

            // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
            if($stmt->execute()){
                // Store result
                $stmt->store_result();

                // Check if username exists, if yes then verify password
                if($stmt->num_rows == 1){                    
                    // Bind result variables
                    $stmt->bind_result($username, $hashed_password);
                    if($stmt->fetch()){
                        if(password_verify($password, $hashed_password)){
                            /* Password is correct, so start a new session and
                            save the username to the session */
                            session_start();
                            $_SESSION['username'] = $username;      
                            header("location: welcome.php");
                        } else{
                            // Display an error message if password is not valid
                            $password_err = 'The password you entered was not valid.';
                        }
                    }
                } else{
                    // Display an error message if username doesn't exist
                    $username_err = 'No account found with that username.';
                }
            } else{
                echo "Oops! Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
            }
        }

        // Close statement
        $stmt->close();
    }

    // Close connection
    $mysqli->close();
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Login</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css">
    <style type="text/css">
        body{ font: 14px sans-serif; }
        .wrapper{ width: 350px; padding: 20px; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <h2>Login</h2>
        <p>Please fill in your credentials to login.</p>
        <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="post">
            <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($username_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
                <label>Username</label>
                <input type="text" name="username"class="form-control" value="<?php echo $username; ?>">
                <span class="help-block"><?php echo $username_err; ?></span>
            </div>    
            <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($password_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
                <label>Password</label>
                <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control">
                <span class="help-block"><?php echo $password_err; ?></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Login">
            </div>
            <p>Don't have an account? <a href="register.php">Sign up now</a>.</p>
        </form>
    </div>    
</body>
</html>
```

**welcome.php**

```
<?php
// Initialize the session
session_start();

// If session variable is not set it will redirect to login page
if(!isset($_SESSION['username']) || empty($_SESSION['username'])){
  header("location: login.php");
  exit;
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Welcome</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css">
    <style type="text/css">
        body{ font: 14px sans-serif; text-align: center; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="page-header">
        <h1>Hi, <b><?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SESSION['username']); ?></b>. Welcome to our site.</h1>
    </div>
    <p><a href="logout.php" class="btn btn-danger">Sign Out of Your Account</a></p>
</body>
</html>
```

**logout.php**

```
<?php
// Initialize the session
session_start();

// Unset all of the session variables
$_SESSION = array();

// Destroy the session.
session_destroy();

// Redirect to login page
header("location: login.php");
exit;
?>
```

My issue is when I open any of my pages, I see these errors:

> **Warning:** mysqli::__construct(): The server requested authentication
>   method unknown to the client [caching_sha2_password] in
>   **C:\Apache24\htdocs\config.php** on **line 10**.
>
> **Warning:** mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/2054): The server requested
>   authentication method unknown to the client in
>   **C:\Apache24\htdocs\config.php** on **line 10**.

I you want to see the **httpd.conf** file of Apache web server, I am also attaching it below:
LoadModule php7_module "c:\php\php7apache2_4.dll"

```
<IfModule php7_module>
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .php
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .html
PHPIniDir "C:\PHP"
</IfModule>
```

I you want to see the **php.ini** file, I am also attaching a few parts of it below:

**Part-I**

```
; Directory in which the loadable extensions (modules) reside.
; http://php.net/extension-dir
; extension_dir = "./"
; On windows:
extension_dir = "ext"
```

**Part-II**

```
;extension=php_bz2.dll
;extension=php_curl.dll
;extension=php_fileinfo.dll
;extension=php_ftp.dll
;extension=php_gd2.dll
;extension=php_gettext.dll
;extension=php_gmp.dll
;extension=php_intl.dll
;extension=php_imap.dll
;extension=php_interbase.dll
;extension=php_ldap.dll
;extension=php_mbstring.dll
;extension=php_exif.dll      ; Must be after mbstring as it depends on it
extension=C:/PHP/ext/php_mysqli.dll
;extension=php_oci8_12c.dll  ; Use with Oracle Database 12c Instant Client
;extension=php_odbc.dll
;extension=php_openssl.dll
;extension=php_pdo_firebird.dll
extension=C:/PHP/ext/php_pdo_mysql.dll
;extension=php_pdo_oci.dll
;extension=php_pdo_odbc.dll
;extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll
;extension=php_pdo_sqlite.dll
;extension=php_pgsql.dll
;extension=php_shmop.dll
```

My Apache web server is working well and also I am also able to view phpinfo(); file. It is as follows:

```
Server API: Apache 2.0 Handler
Virtual Directory Support:  enabled
Configuration File (php.ini) Path:  C:\Windows
Loaded Configuration File:  C:\PHP\php.ini
MysqlI Support: enabled
Client API library version: mysqlnd 5.0.12-dev - 20150407 - $Id: 38fea24f2847fa7519001be390c98ae0acafe387 $
PDO support:    enabled
```

Can someone please tell me how to resolve these errors so that I can successfully login into my website.

Comment: Hard to understand and answer. too Broad question.

Comment: Please google the error message

Answer (score 0):

FOR THIS :

> Warning: mysqli::__construct(): The server requested authentication
>   method unknown to the client [caching_sha2_password] in
>   C:\Apache24\htdocs\config.php on line 10.

your MySQL server is still using the old-password-hash mechanism, which was changed in MySQL 4.1. MySQLP mysqli client is newer and doesn't support the old password mechanism. Since this causes an error.
read this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1340488/mysql-php-incompatibility) for more details its just incompatibility

I also suggest you to use XAMP or WAMP as per your OS which is better option then manual configuration

Comment: thanks Alive to Die for your valuable edit suggestion