# php artisan migrate - Error - Illuminate\Database\QueryException : SQLSTATE[HY000] [2054]

Tags: php, laravel-artisan, migrate

I have the following error upon doing:

```
php artisan migrate
```

Error:

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException : SQLSTATE[HY000] [2054] The server requested authenti cation method unknown to the client (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table _schema = d1 and table_name = migrations)

Here's a screenshot;

[image]

PS. Just in case: I've enabled the "extension=pdo_mysql" in my **php.ini** file.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1340488/mysql-php-incompatibility

Comment: None of these help actually...

Answer (score 7):

Hi as mentioned in this post:

[Laravel-news](https://laravel-news.com/laravel-5-4-key-too-long-error)

it is a typical windows problem.

The mentioned solution is:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

public function boot()
{
    Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
}
```

inside the AppServiceProvider.php

Answer (score 3):

If you use Macos+docker+mysql. then use this

```
 ./vendor/bin/sail artisan migrate
```

not php artisan migrate

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I have also been stuck on this for quite some time. 
One solution that worked for me was to open Connection.php and either comment out the exceptions or replace those exceptions so that there is no error when `php migrate`
is run. This worked for me. Let me know if you find any other solutions/any changes.

**Alternatively, and perhaps a better solution:**

In database.php, found under app/config, add this:

```
'connections' => [

    'mysql' => [
        'driver'      => 'mysql',
        'host'        => env( 'DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1' ),
        'port'        => env( 'DB_PORT', '3306' ),
        'database'    => env( 'DB_DATABASE', 'forge' ),
        'username'    => env( 'DB_USERNAME', 'forge' ),
        'password'    => env( 'DB_PASSWORD', '' ),
        'unix_socket' => env( 'DB_SOCKET', '' ),
        'charset'     => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation'   => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'      => '',
        'strict'      => true,
        'engine'      => null,
        'modes'       => [
            'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',
            'STRICT_TRANS_TABLES',
            'NO_ZERO_IN_DATE',
            'NO_ZERO_DATE',
            'ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO',
            'NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION',
        ],
    ],
],
```

Answer (score 0):

Run the following two commands for ubuntu:

```
sudo apt install php-mysql
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp restart
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to PHP.ini file and watch for
`extension_dir`

It should be aligned with the php version of your project.

Comment: extension_dir = "C:\MAMP\bin\php\php8.1.0\ext"

Comment: So its php version 8 for you

Answer (score 0):

Open XAMPP and start MySQL – it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

**Resolveu pra mim da seguinte forma:**

Em **AppServiceProvider.php** dentro da pasta **app.Providers** inclua informações abaixo.

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

public function boot()
{
    Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
}
```

Desta forma deve resolver o problema!

Comment: Please translate your answer in English.

Answer (score -1):

Been struggling with this problem too. I think it's better to drop and then migrate again the tables first before adding a new table or any changes to your migrations folder. I hope this will solve your problem..

```
php artisan migrate:fresh
```