# Not able to make connection to mysql 8 in php

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to connect to mysql server using php but it gives the following error

```
Connection failed: The server requested authentication method unknown to the client
```

mysql server version is 8.0.12 and php version is 7.2.9.
My code connect to mysql server

```
<?php
$servername = "127.0.0.1";
$username = "root";
$password = "mypassword";
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
echo "Connected successfully";
?>
```

This question has been previously asked before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1340488/mysql-php-incompatibility) but the solution did not work for me so I am asking this again.
Thanks

edit: I re-installed php now it gives the following for the same code

```
This page isn’t working
127.0.0.1 is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500
```

Comment: Maybe have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49948350/phpmyadmin-on-mysql-8-0

Comment: Also https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_default_authentication_plugin

Comment: i have not installed phpMyAdmin @ChrisLear

Comment: No, but the context looks remarkably applicable

Comment: Check this also: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/34024/server-requested-authentication-method-unknown-to-the-client-mysql-old-password

Comment: Nothing seems to work. Installing php < 5.3 may help but i cannot find way to install it

Comment: Have you tried changing the authentication plugin?

Comment: Yes i added this "default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password" to my configuration file. Now it show HTTP ERROR 500

Comment: Check your error log

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem and found that you can change mysql authentication by running the following code via Workbench

```
ALTER USER root@localhost IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'new-password-here'
```